# Laravel,PHP - Error when returning my blade view

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

My master blade view wont display the search results from autocomplete form.Its just refreshing the page and stays the same .I used TypeAhead plugin in my master .My search form is in my master .Any ideas what can be the issue?

My routes:

```
Route::get('search',array('as'=>'search','uses'=>'AutoCompleteController@search'));
Route::get('autocomplete',array('as'=>'autocomplete','uses'=>'AutoCompleteController@autocomplete'));
```

My Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Product;
class AutoCompleteController extends MainController {

      public function search()
    {
        return view('master');
    }

     public function autocomplete(Request $request)
     {

if( !empty(request('query'))){

        $data = Product::select("title")
        ->where("title","LIKE","%{$request->input('query')}%") 


->get(); 
         dd('justrandom');
     $dataJson =$data->toJson();
        return view('master', compact('dataJson'));
}else{ 

  return view ('master', ['dataJson' => false]);

}

    }
}
```

My master blade:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>@if (!empty($title) )
        {{ $title }}  
        @else
        MySite
        @endif</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">  
    <link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="{{ asset('carousel.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>    
    <script>var BASE_URL = "{{ url('')}}/";</script>  


</head>

<header>
    <!-- NAVBAR
================================================== -->
    <body>
        <div class="navbar-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">

                <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/')}}">MySite</a>

                        </div>
                        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" >

                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                                @if( !empty($menu))
                                @foreach($menu as $item)
                                <li><a href="{{ url($item['url'])}}">{{ $item['link'] }}</a></li>
                                @endforeach
                                @endif

                                <li><a href="{{ url('shop')}}">Shop</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="{{ url('shop/checkout')}}">
                                        <img width="20" src="{{ asset('images/shopping-cart.png')}}">  
                                        <div id="total-cart">
                                            @if(! Cart::isEmpty())
                                            {{Cart::getTotalQuantity()}}
                                            @endif
                                        </div>

                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>  

                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                @if(Session::has('user_id'))
                                <li><a href="{{ url('user/edit')}}">{{ Session::get('user_name') }}</a></li>  
                                @if( Session::has('is_admin'))
                                <li><a href="{{ url('cms/dashboard')}}">CMS DASHBOARD</a></li>  
                                @endif
                                <li><a href="{{ url('user/logout')}}">Logout</a></li>
                                @else
                                <li><a href="{{ url('user/signin')}}">Sign In</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{{ url('user/signup')}}">Sign Up</a></li>  

                                @endif
                            </ul>
                            <div class="row">
                            <div class="container">
                                <form method="GET" action="" class="navbar-form navbar-right">

                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="find" class="typeahead form-control" aria-label="Search here..." placeholder="Search here..." autocomplete="off" value="">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="height: 34px; width: 40px" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>

            </div>
        </div>




</header>  <br><br><br><br>


 @if(!empty($dataJson))
    @foreach(json_decode($dataJson, true) as $value)
       {{ $value['record1']['record 2'] }}   
    @endforeach
@endif

<div class="container" >@yield('carousel')</div> <br><br>

<main>  
    <div class="container">

        @include ('inc.sm')
        @include ('inc.errors')


        @yield('content')  

    </div>

</main>  
<br><br><br>
<footer>  
    <div class="container">  
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" >
                <p class="text-center" style="font-size: 18px;" >MySite &copy; {{ date('Y') }} </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</footer>    



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.1/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/script.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    var path = "{{ route('autocomplete') }}";
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        source:  function (query, process) {
        return $.get(path, { query: query }, function (data) {
                return process(data);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

My master blade view wont display the search results from autocomplete form.Its just refreshing the page and stays the same .I used TypeAhead plugin in my master .My search form is in my master .Any ideas what can be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a syntax error, here:

```
@if(!empty($dataJson))
@foreach(json_decode($dataJson, true) as $value)
   {{ $value['record1']['record 2'] }}   
@endforeach
$endif
```

That `$endif` should surely be `@endif` ..?

Comment: yes, that was the issue:)thanks, but the in general I am trying to display results from the search form and my code doesn't work it just refreshing the page and stays the same.How can I display what user searched for

Comment: That sounds like a different question. Maybe we can mark this question as complete, and create another for the current issue you are having - i'll be happy to help.